# Gta 4 Missing Shadow setting

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

Gta 4 runs well on my pc, but I am not sure Why some options in graphics tab are missing... Like Shadow quality, Reflection resolution, Reflection quality, etc:-

[image: Here is the screen shot]

Answer (score 3):

This bug can be fixed by installing Patch 8 for GTA IV and/or Patch 3 for EFLC or any later update, including The Complete edition. From the [download page for Patch 8](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/235650888):

> Fixed a bug that restricted settings changes when using modern video cards.

If you are using the Retail/Disk edition, click [here for IV](https://updates.rockstargames.com/patches/gtaiv/GTA_IV_EFIGS_PATCH_8.exe) or [here for EFLC](https://updates.rockstargames.com/patches/eflc/EFLC_PATCH_3.exe) to download the update. Just open the file and follow the instructions.

For the Steam edition, you should have The Complete Edition with IV, TLAD and TBoGT combined. If the game is updated and you are not running the latest version, [check the integrity of the game](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335):

1. From the **Library** section, right-click on the game and select **Properties** from the menu.
2. Select the Local files tab and click the **Verify integrity of game files...** button.
3. Steam will verify the game's files - this process may take several minutes.